# Unity Multiple Display - Click works only on MainCamera tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, click, game-engine

I've got an issue with multiple displays on Unity 2017.4.0f1. I need to create 3 cameras and display their viewports on 3 different monitors, and that works fine. But, when I try to click an object on another display attached to another camera, click on object not work. It seems that clicking works only on cameras that have the  `MainCamera` tag.

Can anyone help me understand and resolve the issue? Thanks a lot.

---

Edit: Here is the click code:

```cs
Ray raycam;
RaycastHit hit;

Vector2 displayleft = new Vector2(-72, 0);
Vector2 displaycenter = new Vector2(1366, 0);

raycam = cam2.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);


if (Input.mousePosition.x < displaycenter.x && Input.mousePosition.x > 0)
{
    Debug.Log("1");

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        instruction.text = "1";
    }
    raycam = cam1.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

}
else if (Input.mousePosition.x < displayleft.x)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        instruction.text = "2";
    }
    Debug.Log("2");

    raycam = cam2.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
}
else if (Input.mousePosition.x > displaycenter.x)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        instruction.text = "3";
    }
    Debug.Log("3");

    raycam = cam3.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
}

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{

    if (Physics.Raycast(raycam, out hit))

    {

        hit.transform.root.GetComponent<Animator>().speed = 0f;
        GameObject ChildGameObject1 = hit.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        GameObject ChildGameObject2 = ChildGameObject1.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        ChildGameObject2.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("prova", true);

        StartCoroutine(Activation(hit));

    }

}
```

[This is my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzyFo.png)

Comment: What do you mean with _click on game object not work_? Can you share some code that you use?

Comment: Sure, here the code: 

void FixedUpdate() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{

Ray ray;
     RaycastHit hit;
 
     ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
     if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))

       {

        hit.transform.root.GetComponent<Animator>().speed = 0f;
             GameObject  ChildGameObject1 = hit.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
               GameObject  ChildGameObject2 = ChildGameObject1.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
    ChildGameObject2.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("prova", true);
StartCoroutine(Activation(hit));}}}

Comment: I mean that click works fine only on MainCamera displaytarget, but when i switch to another display, click not work

Comment: Please edit the code into your question.

Comment: Your issue is obvious: you are only casting the ray from the Main Camera, given by your `Camera.main` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have not noticed at all the issue!

Comment: Hi! I have problem that make me crazy. I need to raycast 3 different cameras. If i use this code (i update code in question), when i click on a display, take the input also in another cameras, and click not work fine. How can i have 3 separate Raycast of 3 different camera?

Comment: Your issue is rather tricky, since you have to find out which display was clicked. Can you do me a favor and test around with `Input.mousePosition.x` on each monitor and share your resulting values?

Comment: I've resolve, thanks. i didn't notice that the mouseposition change in other monitor, becouse i couldn't try with 3 monitor. Now i tested e i can use input.mousePosition.x to determinate which display was clicked. Thanks for help!

Comment: It seemed simple, but code not work :( If you have patience, can control my script? i update code in question

Answer (score 0):

So I looked into the problem and what you apparently need to do is check on which display the mouse is currently on and depending on that cast the ray from a different camera.

Luckily, I found [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1349602/detect-the-display-of-current-mouse-position-windo.html) code that allows that, which allows us to get the display that the cursor is currently on.

Note that this code is untested and may not work.

First we get the index of the display that our cursor is current on.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePosition lpMousePosition);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MousePosition 
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

private static int GetHoveredDisplay ()
{
    // Get the absolute mouse coordinates
    MousePosition mp;
    GetCursorPos(out mp);
    // Get the relative mouse coordinates
    Vector3 r = Display.RelativeMouseAt(new Vector3(mp.x, mp.y));
    // Use the z coordinate
    int displayIndex = (int)r.z;
    return displayIndex;
}
```

Now, we can insert this index into your code.

We need to create a new array, filled with your display cameras, ordered by their display index.

```cs
public Camera[] cameras;
```

Next, we cast a ray from the camera of the display that the cursor is currently on.

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    int di = GetHoveredDisplay();
    Camera currentDisplayCamera = cameras[di];

    Ray ray = currentDisplayCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        // etc ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. In part works, but i have always the same problem: in this case, raycast works only on first camera that I added in cameras's array. Detect correctly which display is clicked, but the raycast doesn't work fine: for example, if I click at left of display, a trigger on right actived. I think that is resolution problem, becouse all 3 monitor have different resolution. Can be this the problem?

Comment: @CristianGagl Sure, that could be a problem, I guess. I don't have the resources to verify that though, since I only own one display.

Comment: It seems that it isn't resolution problem. I edit my question and add a image showing my configuration. All code works only on one display